# Combine logic of boolean value & integer in one activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let say I have a model named a `Product`. `Product` has a `days_lifetime:integer` in days (it can expire in 1, 2, 3 et.c. days after initialization). But sometimes `Product` has unlimited lifetime (it can be stored infinitively long time). So, I need to add another variable like `unlimited_lifetime:boolean`

Now I have two ways to understand the lifetime of `Product` model:

```
class Product < AR::Base
  def lifetime
    unlimited_lifetime? ? 100000 : days_lifetime # too big integer
  end

  validates :unlimited_lifetime, absence: true, if: 'days_lifetime.present?'
  validates :unlimited_lifetime, presence: true, if: 'days_lifetime.blank?'
  validates :days_lifetime, absence: true, if: 'unlimited_lifetime.present?'
  validatees :days_lifetime, presence: true, if: 'unlimited_lifetime.blank?'
```

But this solution is complex and hardcoded. Is there any software pattern or gem to simplify this approach?

Comment: Why not use `0` or `-1` to indicate this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use existing `days_lifetime` column and put for example `-1` for products with unlimited lifetime(I assume `0` is being used for expired products).